# Formatting issues using RevTex 4.2

Tags: latex

I have been using Revtex 4.2 and notice that there is a lot of trouble formatting.

1. There is excessive spacing after a full-stop or between words. I am now using `\@` to reduce the gap [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZYiZ.png)
2. Between paragraphs, there is more than usual space. I correct this using `\vspace{-1em}` [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxThb.png)

How do I make sure that these issues are corrected automatically?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problems you observe?

Comment: Thanks for adding the output. In general that looks like perfectly fine typography, but if you don't like this, one can disable the french spacing and the parskip. To show you how to do this, it would be helpful if you would provide a [mre] that allows us to reproduce your situation